# The code "df.dropna" in python erases my entire data frame, what is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, pandas, nan, gaussian, naivebayes

I want to drop all NaN variables in one of my columns but when I use `df.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)` it erases my entire dataframe. Why is this happening?

I've used both `df.dropna` and `df.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)` and it doesn't work to remove NaN.

I'm binning my data so i can run a gaussian model but I can't do that with NaN variables, I want to remove them and still have my dataframe to run the model.

Before and AFter
[image: Data]

[image]

Comment: Can you post raw data, your code to recreate your df, and your code that produces the erroneous result. Note to just remove `NaN` from one column you can just do `df['Col'] = df['Col'].dropna()`, what you wrote was to drop rows that contained any `NaN` which would mean that if all your rows contained at least 1 `NaN` then the entire df would be deleted

Comment: try `df.dropna(how='all',axis=0, inplace=True)` if you dont use all, it will remove all rows which has a `NaN`

Comment: It sounds like you have an NaN in every row in some column. Adding to what anky_91 said, you can also have dropna look at only a subset of columns (or rows). So df = df.dropna(subset=["col1_name"]) and it will only drop rows that have NaN values in that column.. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: @EdChum I've shared the before and after dataset

Comment: @pramire1 what are you trying to achieve here? dropna() will drop all rows since one or the other column in each row is a nan

Comment: `CancellationCode` columnn seems to have all `NaNs` so drop that with `drop('CancellationCode', axis=1)` the `dropna`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your case, but sharing the solution that worked on my case:

**The ones that didn't work:**

```
df = df.dropna() #==> make the df empty.
df = df.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True) #==> make the df empty.
df.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True) #==> make the df empty.
```

**The one that worked:**

```
df.dropna(how='all',axis=0, inplace=True) #==> Worked very well...
```

**Thanks to Anky above for his comment.**

Answer (score 1):

Default 'dropna' command uses 'how=any' , which means that it would delete each row which has 'any' NaN

This, as you found out, delete rows which have 'all' NaN columns

```
df.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)
```

or, more basic:

```
newDF = df.dropna(how='all')
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future. Try changing axis=0 to axis=1

```
df.dropna(axis=1, how = 'all')
```